# How can I change the HUD key from the command line?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, hud, gsettings

I know I can change the HUD shortcut key by going into System Settings... > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchers > Key to show the HUD.

I need to do this from the command line, so I can put it in a postinstall script called from preseed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work for me (on Ubuntu 12.04) to set the HUD key to <kbd>Alt</kbd>:

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/show_hud" --type string "<Alt>"
```

I can replace `"<Alt>"` (the default) with the desired keystroke, e.g. `"<Alt>x"` (for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) or `"<Control>"` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Note that if you have a different screen configuration (e.g. multiple monitors), the `"screen0"` in the above key name may need to be changed accordingly.  To find the correct key name(s), do

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-list "/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell"
```

and see where the `show_hud` key appears.